# Unable to connect to mysql database using PHP script

Tags: php, android, mysql-connect

I have two databases on mysql server 'application' and 'test'. I am trying to connect to 'application' db using the following code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3360','root','','application');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
?>
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'application' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ServerScripting.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ServerScripting.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ServerScripting.php on line 4
```

Whereas when I tried to connect to 'test' database it worked giving:

```
Connected successfully
```

I am using XAMPP server. I checked the permissions for each database and all the users are granted with complete access. I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Try `localhost` instead and triple verify that the database called application actually exists

Comment: You should fetch the error as `mysqli_error($link);`

Comment: database application is it really exist??

Comment: I tried localhost too still the same behavior. Yes error should be called with mysqli_error($link) but still the same

Comment: yes exists. I added 2 records using sql.

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale I triple verified the database name and application db exists with 3 tables which are populated too and I am able to fetch the records through phpmyadmin.

Comment: You still get the same error message even after changing to `mysqli_error`??? That doesn't really make sense here, at the absolute very least the function name should have changed. Are you sure you saved the change after editing the function call?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong port number. It should be **3306** instead of 3360.

Answer (score -1):

The XAMPP server's mysql db is running on port 3360 whereas mySQL command line client is on port 3306. So the 'test' db is on port 3360 and 'application' db is on 3306. As testing I queried all the databases available on the server and so came to know the reason behind the error I am facing.

```
<?php
   $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3360','root','');
   if (!$link) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
   }
   echo 'Connected successfully';
   $result = mysqli_query($link , "SHOW DATABASES;");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {        
       echo $row[0]."<br>";        
   }
?>
```